# Follow-Up: rails3 and mongrel issue - ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongrel

This is a follow up question to my question posted yesterday which seems to be "hanging" in mid air after getting some responses from folks that tried to help.

Anyways, the only difference between this time and the previous attempt is that i am using RVM to install an use Ruby 1.9.2. The mongrel is 1.2.0.pre version since mongrel 1.1.5 does not install with Ruby 1.9.2.

My Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '3.0.8'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'mongrel', '>= 1.2.0.pre2'
    gem "cgi_multipart_eof_fix"
    gem "fastthread"
```

And

The error log is as shown below when i run "mongrel_rails cluster::start":

```
 ** Daemonized, any open files are closed.  Look at tmp/pids/mongrel.3000.pid and
 log/mongrel.3000.log for info.
    ** Starting Mongrel listening at 127.0.0.1:3000
    ** Starting Rails with development environment...
    ** Mounting Rails at /home/ec2-user/test_ruby_1.9.2...
    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/lib/active_sup
port/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadE
rror)
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/l
ib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/l
ib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/l
ib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/l
ib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.8/l
ib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/rails.rb:148:in `rails'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/bi
n/mongrel_rails:116:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/bi
n/mongrel_rails:102:in `block in run'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/bi
n/mongrel_rails:86:in `new'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/bi
n/mongrel_rails:86:in `run'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/li
b/mongrel/command.rb:210:in `run'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2/bi
n/mongrel_rails:282:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `l
oad'
        from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `<
main>'
```

Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Addding
    gem 'dispatcher'
to Gemfile seems to help
If dispatcher gem is not a part of your list, then do so by
    gem install dispatcher
Finally do bundle update or bundle install 
Thanks.